# Update one-to-many ArrayList in JPA2.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "First-Search",
    "steps": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "subSearchId": 1,
            "step": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "subSearchId": 1,
            "step": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "subSearchId": 1,
            "step": 3                
        }
    ]
}
```

In this json, i want to update the **steps[]** array element step no. 
if i swap step values , they should update inside db as well,

**Condition**

My table has Unique key constraints on combination of **subSearchId** and **step**

i don't want to delete all the records before update.

is there any best way to update this

**mycontroller**

```
JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        final SubSearch t = Json.fromJson(json, SubSearch.class);
        SubSearchDao tdao = new SubSearchDao();
        SubSearchStepDao stdao = new SubSearchStepDao();
        SubSearch subSearch = tdao.findById(t.id);
        SubSearchStep sst = null;
        SubSearchStep sstTmp = null;
        boolean orderChanged = false;

//        orderChanged = subSearch.steps.stream().filter(p -> p.step != (t.steps.stream().filter(p1 -> p1.id!=null && p1.id.equals(p.id)).findFirst()).get().step).findFirst().isPresent();
        for (int i = 0; i < subSearch.steps.size(); i++) {
            sst = t.steps.get(i);
            sstTmp = subSearch.steps.get(i);
            if (sst.id != null) {
                // true, means steps has been updated
                if (sst.step != sstTmp.step) {
                    orderChanged = true;
//                    sst.id=null;
                }
            }
        }
        if (orderChanged) {
            stdao.deleteAll(subSearch);
            return ok(Json.toJson(tdao.update(t)));
        } else {
            return ok(Json.toJson(tdao.update(t)));
        }
```

right now i am deleting all entries before update, if i get any order changes.

**Database:**

```
      id  subSearchId    step  
------  -----------  --------
    1            1         1
    2            1         3
    3            1         2
```

i want swap **step** and (**subSearchId    step**) is unique.

Comment: Can't you just cascade the update from SubSearch to SubSearchStep with the annotation cascade=ALL and let JPA take care of the update of che child elements when you do `tdao.update()`?

Comment: i don't have issue for cascading, it's the problem for updating values , when i swap steps[0].step with steps[1].step it prompts exception, because second value is already exist , and it is set unique.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like something JPA cannot handle, as there is no way to arrange update statements so that they do not fail.  You will need to set your database to only check the constraints when the transaction is done, not at the statement level.  If that is not possible, you will need to remove the constraint or continue to delete all before making changes.

Comment: Yeah exactly m facing this situation , so will it effect Database performance as well , if i will delete the entries frequently ? rather update them?

Comment: It is extra statements, so it will have an effect.  How much of one though I can't say without profiling your application.

Comment: i removed the constraint , didnt find the proper way to do the update